# XPath query does not match HTML source

Tags: xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

Using [XpathBuilder](http://www.xpathbuilder.com/) I can construct a simple search engine query and pull data out of the search results using XPath. I have some simple examples in a Google spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtT1QPEACWUldE9CZno5WkhzVGZBXzhaMjdNc045Z3c), which runs the query "XPath tutorial" on various search engines and attempts to pull out the number of results each search engine returns.

The formula in that Google spreadsheet is as follows:

```
=importxml("http://www.google.com/search?q="xpath+tutorial"&num=30&pws=0", 
           "//div[@id='resultStats']")
=importxml("http://www.bing.com/search?q=xpath+tutorial&count=30", 
           "//span[@class='sb_count']")
=importxml("http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=xpath+tutorial&n=30", 
           "//span[@id='resultCount']")
```

There are some oddities about this that I don't understand. Firstly, the Google search does not return any results, but the XPath query looks OK. Indeed, there are a number of online tutorials which recommend exactly what I have done here.

The Yahoo query returns the correct result, it's the only one that does.

The number of results found by the Bing Xpath query do not match the results given on the [Bing web page](http://www.bing.com/search?q=xpath+tutorial&count=30), even though there is only one XML node which matches the XPath query. More details are on the [spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtT1QPEACWUldE9CZno5WkhzVGZBXzhaMjdNc045Z3c)

Where did it all go so wrong?

Comment: Downvoting because no code is shown.

Comment: The code was all in the Google Doc which also showed the results and gave some details of the source code from the search engines. I've added some of this to the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

```
=importxml("http://www.google.com/search?q='xpath+tutorial&num=30&pws=0'", "//div[@id='resultStats']")
```

Comment: Wow,well, that worked. It seems like the only difference between my code and yours is the extra quotes around the key/value pairs in the URL. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Google one probably doesn’t work due to the unencoded double-quotation marks in the URL. Since the `importxml` string delimiter character is a double-quotation mark, that’s probably not going to work. Encode the double-quotation marks to `%22`.

Not sure about Bing. Best guess is that your XPath is working but Bing is returning different results to you and Google Docs for some reason.

Comment: OK, I've taken the quotation marks off so now the statement reads `=importxml("http://www.google.com/search?q=xpath+tutorial&num=30&pws=0", "//div[@id='resultStats']")` and the output in the spreadsheet is still the same :(

Comment: @snim2 The only thing I can think of is that the Google search results page sent to Google Docs (which may be different from what you see in your browser) does not contain a div with an id attribute of “resultStats”.

Comment: It's possible, but I can't see why that would be. Also, this clearly /used/ to work as there are a bunch of tutorials that recommend the method I've used!

Answer (score 0):

The devil is in the detail - if you don't show us your code, we can't find your bugs for you.

However, XPath is defined to run against XML whereas you appear to be running it against HTML. So the confusion may be in the way HTML is mapped to XML: for example by the addition of implicit nodes such as tbody, by case-folding, or by namespace handling.

Comment: The point about HTML is an interesting one. I suspect that's why the Google query doesn't work, but it doesn't explain the result from Yahoo.